# UnionBy using ID and update_date greater than

Tags: javascript, lodash

I`m using `lodash` and I need a help with unify two arrays using ID but update the second array only if update_date is greater than other object.

**Example:**

First Array:

```
[
 {
  id:xpto
  name:test
  update_date:1519211809934 //Because I`m using Date.now()
 },
{
  id:testes
  name:nameTest
  update_date:1519211809934 //Because I`m using Date.now()
 }
]
```

Second Array:

```
[
 {
  id:xpto
  name:test
  update_date:1519211809934 //Because I`m using Date.now()
 }
]
```

I know, if I using `_unionBy(array1, array2, id)` the first replace the second, but, how I can add one condition to unify only if update_date is greater than the other object?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`_.unionWith()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#unionWith) to check if the `id` of both objects is the same, and if the `update_date` of the the 1st array item (`a`), is greater than that of the 2nd array item (`b`).

```js
const array1 = [{"id":"xpto","name":"test","update_date":1519211809934},{"id":"testes","name":"nameTest","update_date":1519211809934}]

const array2 = [{"id":"xpto","name":"test","update_date":1519211809934}, {"id":"testes","name":"test","update_date":1}]

const result = _.unionWith(array1, array2, (a, b) =>
  a.id === b.id && a.update_date < b.update_date
)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```